# How can I use either < or > (or other comparative operator) in an expression depending on a function input?

Tags: comparison, metatrader4, mql5, metatrader5

I have two longish blocks of code that are identical except in various comparative statements `>` is switched with `<`, `>=` with `<=` etc. I wanted to put these in a function and use one operator or another depending on a function input.

I am coding in [MQL5](http://www.mql5.com/en/docs/basis) but this is very similar to C++ so hopefully methods that work in this will also be useable in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a comparator function for each comparison you need, and then pass the right function as an argument to the *longish* code blocks (wrapped in a suitably defined function)

As an example, consider the following hypothetical case where a function (`myFunc`) receives 2 integers(`a` and `b`)
and processes them. The processing steps are similar except for the type of comparison done on the arguments. We get around the problem by providing `myFunc` with the *right tool* for comparison.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool comp1(int a, int b) {
    return a > b;
}

bool comp2(int a, int b) {
    return a < b;
}

void myFunc(int a, int b, bool (*myComp)(int, int)) {
    bool res = myComp(a, b);
    cout << "value : " << res << endl;
}
int main()
{
    myFunc(1, 2, comp1); //use >
    myFunc(1, 2, comp2); //use <
    return 0;
}
```

Clearly, `comp1` and `comp2` are the 2 different comparators. We pass one of them to `myFunc` depending on the requirements (`<` or `>`).

The best thing is that your comparisons can now be as complex as you want, and `myFunc` is oblivious to the complexities.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately that doesn't seem to work in my environment. Do you know any other ways?

Comment: @whitebloodcell What are the restrictions that make this "not work" in your environment?

Comment: @whitebloodcell No idea about `mql5`, but one way of going about it might be to brainstorm and make sure that the ` longish blocks of code` are really necessary. Maybe you can restructure the code in a way that the operator dependent part is minimal.

Comment: By "not work" I just meant that the example you provided would not compile in my environment unfortunately. MQL5 is an object oriented language with syntax very similar to C++ (quoting from the creators). I can make use of encapsulation and extensibility of types, inheritance, polymorphism, overloading and virtual functions, pointers etc, but not your solution unfortunately.

Comment: It's valid C++ code but unfortunately MQL [doesn't support pointers to function](http://forum.mql4.com/4630)

Answer (score 2):

Coding in [MQL4](http://docs.mql4.com/) you haven't pointers to function / templates. [MQL5](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs) has templates but formal parameter types are **only built-in or basic user-defined types**.

You could try something like:

```
enum COMPARATOR
{
  C_EQUAL = 0,
  C_LESS = 1,
  C_GREATER = -1
  C_AT_MOST = 2,
  C_AT_LEAST = -2,
};

bool cmp(int a, int b, COMPARATOR c)
{
  switch (c)
  {
  case C_LESS:     return a < b;
  case C_AT_MOST:  return a <= b;
  case C_EQUAL:    return a == b;
  case C_AT_LEAST: return a >= b;
  case C_GREATER:  return a > b;
  }

  Alert("INTERNAL ERROR: UNKNOWN COMPARISON");
  return false;
}

void a_function(COMPARATOR c)
{
  if (cmp(MathRand(), 13, c))
    Print("BOOM");

  // *** If you need the "opposite" of c *** you can write:
  if (cmp(Time[0], Time[1], COMPARATOR(-c))
    Alert("DONE");
}
```

It isn't elegant but it's effective.

Answer (score 1):

Pass in a "comparator" as a function or functor, in this case I'm using the [`std::less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) and [`std::greater`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) functors defined in the [`functional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional) header, there are functors defined for more or less all the operators.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename Comparator>
void do_something(Comparator comp)
{
   int a = 1;
   int b = 2;

   if (comp(a, b)) {
      std::cout << "expression was true" << std::endl;
   } else {
      std::cout << "expression was not true" << std::endl;
   }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   do_something(std::greater<int>());
   do_something(std::less<int>());
}
```

Output:

```
expression was not true
expression was true
```

Comment: In C++ this is a valid approach but unfortunately MQL5 doesn't support class templates / complex template formal parameters (i.e. functions / functors).